# After migrating to yarn 3 workspace "Cannot use import statement outside a module" running react-scripts test

Tags: javascript, node.js, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces, yarnpkg-v2

I have a repository with yarn 3 workspaces and a CRA front end located in `/packages/client`

`yarn workspace client start` successfully launches the development app on port 3000.

The test suite ran correctly before moving the client to the `packages` folder and setting up the yarn workspace. I have made no changes to the client's `package.json`.

Running `yarn workspace client test` gives:

```
Error: Failed to initialize watch plugin "../../.yarn/__virtual__/jest-watch-typeahead-virtual-2d80f0ed7c/0/cache/jest-watch-typeahead-npm-1.0.0-0c228b0e38-388d518974.zip/node_modules/jest-watch-typeahead/build/file_name_plugin/plugin.js":

  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/bob/monorepo/.yarn/__virtual__/jest-watch-typeahead-virtual-2d80f0ed7c/0/cache/jest-watch-typeahead-npm-1.0.0-0c228b0e38-388d518974.zip/node_modules/jest-watch-typeahead/build/file_name_plugin/plugin.js:1

import { Prompt } from 'jest-watcher';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      28077 |     try {
      28078 |       module.isLoading = true;
    > 28079 |       module.load(modulePath);
            |              ^
      28080 |       hasThrown = false;
      28081 |     } finally {
      28082 |       module.isLoading = false;

      at Function.external_module_.Module._load (../../.pnp.cjs:28079:14)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?